# Writing a Windows Shell Extension similiar to the Assembly Cache Viewer

Tags: c#, shell-extensions

I would like to write a shell extensions to completely customize the display of a particular folder, ala the Assembly Cache Viewer (browse to c:\windows\assembly and you will see what I mean).
Which COM interfaces are responsible for providing these hooks?
My 'viewer' will be written in C#...

Thanks!

Comment: And the winner is:
http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an article that should get you on your way:

- [Create Namespace Extensions for Windows Explorer with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188741.aspx)

> Extending the Windows shell with namespace extensions allows you to create some custom functionality for Windows Explorer. One common use is to enable Explorer **to present a list of items that do not exist in one real folder**, but actually reside in a number of places. The view on the folder makes it look like these items are in one place, so managing them becomes easier. This article illustrates the process of creating **custom shell namespace extensions using C#** and the .NET Framework. [...]

Comment: I have tried this code... and used it by calling:

ShellFolder.RegisterFunction(typeof(Class1));

But it doesnt appear to do anything... does it not work on Vista?

Answer (score 7):

Note that there is [controversy about doing explorer extensions in .NET](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1428326d-7950-42b4-ad94-8e962124043e/).

Example problem: If you target .NET 2.0, then your extension won't work in any "open file" dialogs shown by .NET 1.1 applications. A process can load only one version of the .NET runtime.

It's not just a matter of your extension not working; you will be injecting a particular version of the .NET runtime into *any* application that uses file dialogs. That's bad news if the app is an unmanaged application that was planning on loading a COM component targetting a newer version of the .NET runtime, etc.

**edit**: as explained in the comment, this has now been solved by the .NET 4.0 runtime. Therefore, managed explorer extensions should always target .NET 4.0 or later.

Comment: The latest .Net 4.0 runtime supports in process side-by-side loading of the .Net 4.0 runtime (and ALL future runtimes) with earlier .Net runtimes.

See following excerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx 
"With the ability to have multiple runtimes in process with any other runtime, we can now offer general support for writing managed shell extensions—even those that run in-process with arbitrary applications on the machine."